# What's the point of [HiddenInInspector] (as opposite to [NonSerialized])?

Tags: unity

I understand the difference between `[HiddenInInspector]` and `[NonSerialized]`, what I'm missing is the use case for `[HiddenInInspector]`: so far every time I've encountered it, it was used by developers who weren't aware of `[NonSerialized]`, that would actually have meant to use that. The result is that they risked to get unexpected values when the variable in question was deserialized.

So, in which case it turns out to be useful to hide something from the inspector but to serialize it? If there is such case, are there any known precautions to take in order to prevent unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `[HiddenInInspector]` quite often. 2 recent use cases I encountered:

**First Motivation: Properties that must be serialized but user doesn't need to be aware of and shouldn't modify explicitly.**

Example: I wrote a Behavior Tree plugin these days. You can edit the tree layout graphically through an editor extension (a UI similar to Mecanim). Every node is represented by a `ScriptableObject` that as a `Rect` defining its bounds marked with `[HiddenInInspector]` attribute. This way the user is allowed to layout the tree nodes only interacting through the gui and not accessing directly the `ScriptableObject`. In addition to **prevent possible errors** and inconsistency it helps to **keep the node inspectors clean** from data not relevant to user interaction.

**Second Motivation: Minimize Custom inspector code**

Example: suppose you need to write some custom inspector code. In my use case I need to guarantee that certain serialized property are not set directly but through class methods to produce the required side effects (es. when add a child to a node must also update the parent reference in the child class.).

I need to write a custom inspector but the target class has a lot of properties, and I need to customize only a few. I can mark the property I need to manage explicitly with `[HiddenInInspector]` , call `base.OnInspectorGUI` from the custom inspector code (which draw every other property in the default way) and just write a bunch of line of codes to customize access to the required fields.

> If there is such case, are there any known precautions to take in
>   order to prevent unexpected behaviour?

`SerializedProperty` are initialized with their default value. Btw in the most common scenarios when you hide them is because you are setting them explicitly somewhere else, so it's up to your custom code to make the relevant checks. In any case unexpected behaviors are potentially the same of a normal serialized property.

Answer (score 0):

HiddenInInspector is useful when you want to serialize something derived from other settings, and not have to have code in the Awake method or elsewhere to make sure that the hidden value has the correct derived value when instances are deserialized. This puts the burden of computing or extracting the derived value from the other settings on the editor code, instead of on the GameObject scripting logic, and thus not part of the released game code.

I've only once found a use for HiddenInInspector when I was creating some GUI extensions to an existing GUI framework to create a dynamic inspector element that used reflection on the data object to be edited in the inspector. I used HiddenInInspector to hide the cached reflection data so that it was serialized and didn't have to be frequently rebuilt.

There may be other uses, but that is the only one I've run into so far.